# i18next::pluralResolver: Your environment seems not to be Intl API compatible, use an Intl.PluralRules polyfill

Tags: react-native, i18next

Please help me.

**Error -**

> i18next::pluralResolver: Your environment seems not to be Intl API compatible, use an Intl.PluralRules polyfill. Will fallback to the compatibilityJSON v3 format handling

**Code -**

```js
    import i18n from "i18next";
    import english from './englist.json';
    import thai from './thai.json';
    import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
    i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
        lng:'th',
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        resources:{
            en:english,
            th:thai
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false 
        },
        react:{
            useSuspense:false,
        }
    });
    export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Look like an issue on android.

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  compatibilityJSON: 'v3', <--- add this line.
  lng:'th',
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  resources:{
    en:english,
    th:thai
  },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false 
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense:false,
 }
});
```

It should resolve your issue. You might need to check [this](https://www.i18next.com/misc/migration-guide).

Have fun.

Comment: This only helps if you don't need/use pluralisation. If you need the pluralisation see my answer and use the intl-pluralrules package.

Answer (score 87):

I've had the same issue, and using the `compatibilityJSON V3` mode meant that this broke on my IOS emulators because I actually use pluralisation and am on the latest version (v21) of **i18n-next**

In my case I could fix it by polyfilling `intl-pluralrules`

Have a look at https://github.com/eemeli/intl-pluralrules & https://www.i18next.com/misc/migration-guide

### Installation

```
npm install intl-pluralrules
```

### Polyfill

To use as a polyfill, just import it to ensure that `Intl.PluralRules` is
available in your environment:

```js
import 'intl-pluralrules'
```

If `Intl.PluralRules` already exists,
includes a `selectRange()` method,
and supports [multiple locales](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html),
the polyfill will not be loaded.